# Apache Virtual host Point 2 domains to same root with different index

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I am new to VPS hosting.... and giving a try to digital ocean Linux VPS. I need to point 2 domains to my PHP app. That is located at var/www/html

I want my first domain to point to the root so that it can launch index.php by default.

I also have a login.php page in the same document root...and want my second domain to directly point to this file...e.g. var/www/html/login.php

This is how my Virtual Host for domain1 looks like inside /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@domain1.com
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

this works great for both domains but when I am trying to change the line

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/login.php
```

The second domain is not loading css and js files for the page. I am not sure what can be an easy and safe way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second VH definition you could try changing the `DirectoryIndex` to point to the login script like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@domain2.com
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    DirectoryIndex login.php

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```